# Percent symbol with FontFamily setting looks weird in Dendrogram

Tags: bugs, fonts, trees

**Bug introduced in 12.3.1 or earlier, persisting through 13.3.1.**

---

```mathematica
a = {"one", "b", "你好%"}; b = RandomInteger[1, {3, 40}]; c = 
 AssociationThread[a, b]; Dendrogram[c]
```

produces this

[image]

That is all right. If there is `"XITS"` font in the string, the result is not right.

```mathematica
a1 = StringReplace[a, 
  "%" -> ToString[
    Style["%", FontFamily -> "XITS", 
     PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}], 
    StandardForm]]; c1 = AssociationThread[a1, b]; Dendrogram[c1]
```

produces

[image]

The `"XITS"` font can be replaced by other font to reproduce the issue. How to repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have put more effort in creating a minimal sample. The issue isn't related to Chinese, nor is it related to XITS font. The following is a minimal sample reproducing the issue:

```
plot := Dendrogram[{ToString[
    Style["%", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}], StandardForm], 1}]
plot
```

[image]

What has happened? It seems that the function `Short` has been mistakenly used internally:

```
plot // InputForm
```

[image]

So it's reasonable to guess, disable `Short` may fix the issue, and it's indeed the case:

```
Block[{Short = Identity}, plot]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the question.